# Pagination in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, kaminari

I had got a task to do pagination.When i am doing pagination i had got these error

```
NoMethodError in ProductsController#index

undefined method `page' for []:ActiveRecord::Relation

Rails.root: /home/nithinv/store
Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace

app/controllers/products_controller.rb:4:in `index'
```

This is my controller

```
 def index

       @products = Product.order(:name).page(params[:page]).per(2)

      respond_to do |format|
        format.html  #index.html.erb
        format.json { render :json=> @products }
      end
     end
```

This is my index.html.erb

```
 <% title "Products" %>

<%= paginate @products %>

<% for product in @products %>
  <div class="product">
    <h2><%= link_to product.name, product %></h2>
    <div class="details">
      <%= number_to_currency(product.price) %> |
      Released <%= product.released_at.strftime("%B %e, %Y") %>
    </div>
  </div>
<% end %>

<p><%= link_to "New Product", new_product_path %></p>
```

How can i solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ref [this](https://github.com/amatsuda/kaminari)

I think you forgot to add following line in your `gemfile`

```
gem 'kaminari'
```

and then bundle install

Answer (score 0):

I looks that the problem has to do with kaminari gem configuration (not your code). I'd recommend you to do this quick check:

1. Run `bundle install`
2. Restart the server (because changes may not have been loaded)
3. Check your gemfile because, kaminari gem may is misplaced (under :test group)

A bit obvious, but in occasions I've also found myself wasting time after forgetting some basic checks.